# Add a button inside chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a button that is placed inside the chart to export the graph to an excel file.
I messed around with MapAreas but I couldn't figure out how to set the map area to an image or a control. Is there a different way to accomplish this feature? The button needs to be somehow attached to the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that an ASP.NET chart control is just an image and when you create MapAreas you basically specify *clickable* spots on this image, therefore (as far as I know) a MapArea cannot have a custom background image or a custom control.

Instead use a custom legend:

**Source:**

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" OnClick="Chart1_Click1">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series YValuesPerPoint="2" IsVisibleInLegend="false" Name="Series1" ChartType="Column">
                <Points>
                    <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Product 1" YValues="100" />
                    <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Product 2" YValues="300" />
                </Points>
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Title="Export options:">
                <CustomItems>
                    <asp:LegendItem
                    Name="Export To Excel" 
                    PostBackValue="Export From Legend"  
                    Color="Green">
                    </asp:LegendItem>
                </CustomItems>
            </asp:Legend>
        </Legends>
    </asp:Chart>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Chart1_Click1(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PostBackValue == "Export From Legend")
    {
       //Handle the exporting to Excel
    }
}
```

**End result:**

[image]